# Can I use a variable as the name of a control in Microsoft Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a Microsoft Access Popup Form which I use to lookup addresses. Once the user has found the postcode, the address is then put into various text boxes on the form it was launched from. The problem is, this popup form is launched from various forms throughout the database and so the text boxes it puts the result into are in different locations.

I tried to work around this in the following way. I have a switchboard which is open at all times so I have a hidden Textbox on there which I programmatically put the name of the form I am launching the popup form from. I then declare a string variable which is set to the current value of this hidden textbox like so:

```
Dim currentForm As String
currentForm = [Forms]![foo]![bar]
```

I then tried to put my address details into the relevant textboxes like so:

```
Forms!currentForm![txtCurrentAdd1] = rst![Line1]
```

However this isn't working as planned, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: To get the current form, just use `Me` !

Comment: @iDevelop that will only work within the current form, whereas I reckon Heisenburg means the form to be written to, yesno?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either:

```
Dim currentForm As String
''Not sure where the two parts are coming from
''but you cannot have them like that
currentForm = "foobar"

Forms(currentForm).[txtCurrentAdd1] = rst![Line1]
```

Or

```
Dim currentForm As Form
Set currentForm = Forms![foobar]

currentForm![txtCurrentAdd1] = rst![Line1]
```

You might like to read up on bang vs dot.

Mind you, the whole thing looks a little like you are swimming upstream.

Comment: Thankyou for the help, I will make a point of reading up on bang vs dot.

Comment: The second example must be `Set currentForm = Forms![foobar]`.  Also, if I understand correctly, the "two parts" are a form and the text box.  So the correct answer is `Forms(Forms!foo!bar)!txtCurrentAdd1 = rst!Line1` (or some variant syntax, of course)

Comment: @phhog, I'll accept the set corection, but the second part I am referring to cannot be the textbox - the op says form!foo!bar and then refers to the textbox, bar cannot be the textbox and it cannot be a subform.

Comment: Why do you think bar can't be a text box?  The OP says that it is a hidden text box holding the name of a form which in turn holds a text box (txtCurrentAdd1) where he is adding data.

Comment: I voted up your comment as well Phoog, thanks for explaining =)

Answer (score 6):

You can access controls on other forms like this:

```
Dim FormName As String
Dim ControlName As String

FormName = "YourForm"
ControlName = "YourTextbox"

Forms(FormName).Controls(ControlName) = "New Value"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the OpenArgs property. To open your reusable popup, use:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="frmPopup", OpenArgs:=Me.Name
```

in order to pass the caller's name.

In the frmPopup, you can refer to `Me.OpenArgs` to get that information.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but this might be useful for new readers. The simple way I get round the problem of passing variables between modules and forms is to use the VBA registry area. It's a very simple and easy to use technique and keeps projects nice and clean.

To save a value:

```
SaveSetting AppName, Section, Key, Setting
```

To get the value:

```
GetSetting AppName, Section, Key, [Default]
```

This avoids loosing track of variables and creating hidden controls on forms. It also works cross platform without change on a PC and a Mac.

I then usually set a load of constants in my projects to define the first three parameters:

```
Public Const REG_PROD = "My product name"
Public Const REG_CONFIG = "Configuration"
Public Const REG_SETTING1 = "My Setting 1"
```

So the above calls would become:

To save a value:

```
SaveSetting REG_PROD, REG_CONFIG, REG_SETTING1, "My Value"
```

To get the value:

```
GetSetting REG_PROD, REG_CONFIG, REG_SETTING1, "Value not set"
```

I used to use the hidden control method but it adds a lot of management and you can't always the variable values whereas you can keep an instance of RegEdit open for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1):

I think

```
Me.Controls(variablelabelName).Caption
```

you can write code to make the variable change and use as the `label`'s name to create the unique caption for each label.